# CORS issues with Spring 4.2.0.RC2 and Tomcat 8.0.23

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Before I was using Spring 4.1.x release and had my own Cors Filter and Interceptor. I was also using Tomcat 8.0.8 all was good.

As I had moved the same application to Tomcat 8.0.23 CORS stopped working.

Therefore, I had the application updated to the following versions of Spring dependencies as of my POM:

```
org.springframework: 4.2.0.RC2
org.springframework.security: 4.0.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.security.oauth2: 2.0.7.RELEASE
org.springframework.ws.version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
spring.data.commons.core.version: 1.4.1.RELEASE
```

Now, I had also updated my securityConfiguration.xml to have the proper schemas for security 4.0.1.RELEASE.

The application works fine, all changes perfectly except for CORS.

So I had followed the instructions and added to my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implementation class the following:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        Properties prop = null;

        try {

            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "/com/nando/config/cors.properties");
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);
            in.close();            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            prop = null;
        }

        if (prop != null) {
            String domains = prop.getProperty("allowed.origins");

            List<String> allowedOrigins = new ArrayList<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(domains.split(",")));

            if (allowedOrigins.size() > 0) {
                String[] arrayOrigins = null;
                arrayOrigins = new String[allowedOrigins.size()];
                arrayOrigins = allowedOrigins.toArray(arrayOrigins);
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(arrayOrigins)
                .allowedMethods("PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
                .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
            }
        } else {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
        }
    }
```

Just doing that alone does not fix the problem, although using a debugger to Tomcat I can see that being properly executed and added. I have a properties file so that I can change allowed domains without recompiling the application as I had done before with my own implementation on 4.1.x Spring.

Because I had this application as an OAuth2 application I had implemented an interceptor too.

On my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implementation I had an interceptor before, so I had tried to add it to it as so:

```
@Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CORSInterceptor());
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
```

Which loads my CORSInterceptor implemention as follows:

```
package com.nando.api.filters;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

/**
 * 
 * @author Nando
 *
 */
@Component
public class CORSInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private Properties prop = new Properties();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/nando/config/cors.properties");
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();

        String domains = prop.getProperty("allowed.origins");

        Set<String> allowedOrigins = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(domains
                .split(",")));

        String originHeader = "";
        originHeader = request.getHeader("Origin");

        if (null != originHeader) {
            for (String s : allowedOrigins) {
                if (originHeader.contains(s)) {
                    if (!response.getHeaderNames().contains("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")) {
                        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                                originHeader);
                    }
                    if (!response.getHeaderNames().contains("Access-Control-Allow-Methods")) {
                        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                                "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
                    }
                    if (!response.getHeaderNames().contains("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")) {
                        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                    }
                    if (!response.getHeaderNames().contains("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")) {
                        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                            "Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, x-Requested-with, Accept, Accept-Enconding, X-CSRF-Token");
                    }
if (!response.getHeaderNames().contains("Access-Control-Max-Age")) {
 response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And still will not make a difference.

I do not want to add the CORS filter to Tomcat as it will not allow me to set the domains on a properties file, forcing me to edit the Tomcat instances configuration every time a domain is added or removed.

Looks like I have a conundrum here.

Also I thought that by following Spring 4.2 directions on setting up CORS would make it easier which is not the case.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Carlos.

Comment: could you give some examples of HTTP requests+responses that demonstrate what's not working? Also, I think you should only use your filter/interceptor or better, use the new Spring CORS support, but not both.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use Spring CORS support, I think you should :

- Change `allowedMethods("PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")` to `allowedMethods("PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")` (it is a varargs parameter)
- Remove `allowedHeaders("*")`, it is already the defaults
- Remove your `CORSInterceptor`
- Remove Tomcat CORS Filter
- Check that it works without Spring Security
- As proposed by Brian, give us more details with the HTTP requests/responses

As an alternative, be aware that Spring Framework 4.2 GA also provides a [`CorsFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CorsFilter.html) implementation that could be used in combinaison with [`UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.html) to provide global CORS support.

If you are using Spring Boot (which supports `Filter` beans), it could be something like this in one of your `@Configuration` annotated classes:

```java
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
    config.addExposedHeader("Content-Type");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: First off, thanks for answering, indeed went to look the source code and it is an array not a comma separated string as I had used before. However, that does not fix the probem. Here's why: I am using Spring Security, MVC and I also have an OAuth2 authorization layer I wrote. Before I had the interceptor because, as it gets redirected to pass through OAuth2 authentication/Authorization it needs to make sure the headers are still set for CORS as it gets redirected. At this point, I would like to add the interceptor again and try with it but I was also puzzled by Steve's commets at the blog.

Comment: Have a function on every @RestEndpoint class I have called discover(). I list all the endpoints on this class.Here's the snipet and the full story URL I am copying bellow.

@ RequestMapping(value = { "endpoint1", "endpoint2", "endpoint3" }, method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS, produces = {
"application/json;charset=utf-8", "text/json;charset=utf-8" })
@ ResponseBody
@ ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<void> discover() {
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.add("Allow", "OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT");
return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

}

Comment: Could you provide a sample project in order to allow me to find to best way to solve your issue?

Comment: Here's something interesting. On my code, I load my security configuration via XML. as so:

@ImportResource({ "classpath:com/nando/config/securityConfiguration.xml" })

public class RootContextConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer,
  SchedulingConfigurer {

Comment: Sebatien Deleuze, wish I could but not allowed. For me the issue is that the header is replaced within OAuth2 filter I have. As addCorsMappings runs, it seems to remove the Authorization header.

Comment: This is a very similar project to mine. Also has an OAuth2 implementation, xml security and a CORS Filter on it, https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider

Comment: I have added some details about an alternative solution based on the `CorsFilter` implementation included in Spring Framework 4.2 GA, I hope that will help you for your Spring Security OAuth2 use case ...

Comment: @SébastienDeleuze Perhaps I have overlooked something. Do you mind having a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275299/delete-http-localhost8080-connectserviceprovider-facebook-405-method-not-al